# How can I flip a Webrtc stream with javascript?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have an incoming Webrtc stream that I would like to flip vertically in JS right when we first access it.  In the rest of the code, I'm manipulating the size and including a flip button as well, so I need it to be flipped before it enters the variable.  When I use CSS to flip it, it shows the wrong part of the manipulated stream.

Here's the section of code I'm attempting to update.  I attempted running the two commented lines separately, but neither worked.  They are coming up with undefined/null errors since the stream doesn't exist in this part of the code.  Is there another way to do it at this point of the code?  Thanks for the help!!!

```
function handleTrackEvent(e) {
    /* e.streams[0].style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)'; */
    partnerVideo.current.srcObject = e.streams[0];
    /* document.getElementById('partnerVideo').style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)'; */
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using CSS

```
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1)
```

Comment: When I use CSS, it captures the wrong section of the video, unfortunately.

Comment: Provide a working demo. I can help you fix the code.

Comment: It's a large React app.  I'm attempting to alter the second user video feed.  Here is a working Heroku version - https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/ww-production.  I'm not sure of the best way to share the code since it's so large.  What do you think?